# Explain this Pun "A Slice of New York"

Tags: phrases, puns

How would you describe "A Slice of New York" as a pun?

Comment: Needs context - is this a play on NY style pizza, "the Big Apple", or products such as upstate NY cheddar?

Comment: It seems to be the name of a chain of pizza restaurants in California (whatever else it is).

Comment: In any case, it's not a pun.

Comment: A pizza restaurant named "A slice of life" would be word play on the notion of the short hand reference to  a piece of a pizza as a 'slice'  within the Idiom where slice is used metaphorically used to mean "an aspect of the human experience" in  a broad way.    It is wordplay - it depends on how broad your definition of pun is and whether you regard a "slice" of pizza a different use of the word "slice" than "slice" of life.  I believe the word is used to similar meaning in both ... so Not really a pun.

Comment: A different meaning of 'slice' is it's meaning where a struck golfball peals off in a curve to the right.   If a Pizza joint on a golf course were called "Slices Right"  .. that would be a double pun .. a pun on the use of Slice to refer to pizza portion shorthand, the golf term slice, and the meaning of "right" as in correct as well as "right" as in direction.

Comment: It is a metaphor!!

Comment: @user3850720 well "A slice of New York" (or life) is a metaphor without it applying to pizza at all .   When you name a restaurant that you're using the metaphor in a playful situation where an idiom no longer means the metaphor but the closer to the real meaning?

Comment: Please tell us what you understand the pun to be and what and where you found this phrase. Not everyone lives in the US, and presuming that everyone will be familiar with the slogan is naive. With that said, it appears to be the name of a [**pizza catering** company **in NY**](http://asliceofny.com/about/). Pizzas are often cut into slices; therefore, you are ordering/eating  **a slice of** pizza made in **NY**

Comment: This doesn't mean that the slogan (or brand) cannot be interpreted in more than one way, but you give us nothing to elaborate on. And I mean "nothing".

Comment: @Tom22  it's = it is.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love pizza too. But I immediately thought of **cheesecake**, because NY style cheesecake is often sold by the slice.